# jQuery serialize error with textarea filed

Tags: jquery, serialization, markitup

I'm using this function, to submit form in the background, with custom messages. It works perfectly, except with textarea fields. I've read that the serialize function has problems with ex. linebreaks.

```
 $(function() {
      $("#comment_form").validate({    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('/u/r/l/', $("#comment_form").serialize(),
 function(data) {
            $('#comment_container').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
```

The textarea is a markitup! editor area.

Comment: Please format your code to use newlines and tabulations :)

Comment: I've did, the editor ruined it. But thx ;)

Comment: Take a look here, it may help: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/#comment-67394779

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not jumping to wrong conclusions: are you trying to have the markitup textarea (that the user himself is changing) be serialized into data to send to the server?

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Maybe the solution will be that Achonix has linked, but i'm only beginner in jquery, and can't implent that to my script :S. (I'm rather a XHTML+CSS, designer pro :P )

Comment: Why are you using formSerialize instead of just serialize?

Comment: I assume that you gave the textarea a name attribute and put it inside the form?

Comment: Liam: I've mentioned, that was just a mistake in my post.
thejh: Of course. Normal post of the form works ok... Just the ajaxed jquery one not. I'm using this script on others forms, where no texarea found, with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/#comment-67394779

```
function keepLB (str) { 
  var reg=new RegExp("(%0A)", "g");
  return str.replace(reg,"%0D$1");
}

$(function() {
  $("#comment_form").validate({ submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('/u/r/l/', keepLB($("#comment_form").formSerialize()), function(data) {
      $('#comment_container').html(data);
    });
  }
});
```

If it doesn't work, manually urlencode the textarea data:

```
$(function() {
  $("#comment_form").validate({ submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('/u/r/l/', "textareadata="+escape($("#mytextarea").value), function(data) {
      $('#comment_container').html(data);
    });
  }
});
```

And if you also want to send other form contents (note: don't give the textarea a "name" here, just an id!):

```
$(function() {
  $("#comment_form").validate({ submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('/u/r/l/',
    $("#comment_form").formSerialize()+"&textareadata="+escape($("#mytextarea").value),
    function(data) {
      $('#comment_container').html(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't submit my comment at all :S

Comment: @wintercounter: Which one? The second one only sends the textareas content.

Comment: I have many hidden fields too generated by the CMS so that wouldn't be ok.
If the textareas name is "comment", than this: <?php echo $_POST["comment"]; ?> should print the jQuery'ed request?

Comment: In this example, the data gets sent under the name "textareadata" and gets read from the element with the id "mytextarea".

Comment: In a few words:
This is a Comment form. Just to imagine: there's the form, under that the comments.
And all this is being reloaded, on the submission of the form.
Now with the 3rd script i've got a data back: undefined
It's from PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: I assume that jquery couldn't get the content from the textarea :S

Comment: What a lame am i :) There this before the POST:  $(".comment_wrapper").html("Loading..."); so it deletes the full form -.- Sry guys, and thanks everything ;

Answer (score 0):

One thought (if standard usage of jQuery serialize isn't working) is that the markitup code is taking that textarea and do something fancy with it so that it doesn't even act like a textarea anymore. Is there some way in Markitup API to retrieve the data perhaps?

Comment: It surely have, but don't how to use :S

Comment: Tried without markitup with a plain textarea. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here main_post_txt is the id of html text area element which you are using and in jquery you can get easily its value by using

```
var post_text = $("#main_post_txt").serialize();
```