# Textarea in a form is not submitting via POST with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

For a reason that is unknown to me, my form is not submitting the text typed into my `<textarea>`.

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST', 
url:'****.php', 
data:$('#blogForm').serialize(),
success: function(responseSubmit) { blah blah etc...
```

The inputs work just fine, and correctly post to my database.

The form is:

```
<form id="blogForm">
                        <input type="date" name="date" id="blogDate">
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="blogTitle">
                        <textarea name="blogContent" id="blogBody"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="blogSubmit">
                    </form>
```

And what I get when I inspect in firebug, the POST is:
`date=09%2F25%2F1986&title=Title&blogContent=`

As you can see, the blogContent is empty. Why is this?

Comment: I can't see anything noticeably wrong with what you've posted and jQuery serializes `<textarea>` elements just fine in my experience. When is the `$.ajax()` function being called?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://forum.jquery.com/topic/textarea-and-ajax-with-serialize-help

Comment: Are there line breaks in the data? It might be this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115457/jquery-serialize-error-with-textarea-filed

Comment: Is blogContent more than just a textarea, perchance? i.e. -- is it a tinymce/ckeditor?

Comment: It works just fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bCZy/).

Comment: It is an WYSIWYG text editor... called nicEditor. The ajax function is being called when the submit button is clicked. So far, there wasnt any line breaks that I noticed. I will double check that though.

Comment: @JoryCunningham I think that's been fixed in more recent versions of jQuery (that question/answer is from nearly two years ago), but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Since it works in the fiddle, it must be the WYSIWYG editor attached to it...

Comment: I imagine your WYSIWYG is doing something to that field that makes jquery not want to serialize it.  Can you try to encodeURIcomponent and manually add the value to the serialized string?

Comment: One way to solve this is to go directly on the inputs: `$('#blogForm input, #blogForm textarea').serialize()`

Comment: It was my WYSIWYG editor... Thanks for the help. I guess Ill go with another one, or build it myself ;P  Thanks

Comment: use this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115457/jquery-serialize-error-with-textarea-filed

Comment: your missing the value attribute in your input fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I neglected to mention that I had a WYSIWYG editor attached to the text area, called nicEditor. Apparently there is a bug that forced jQuery to not serialize the textarea. Once the nicEditor was removed, it worked fine. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
   data:$('#blogForm').serialize(),
```

To:

```
   data:$('#blogForm').find('input, select, textarea, button').serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return false onsubmit

```
<code>
<form id="blogForm" onsubmit="return(false);">  
    <input type="date" name="date" id="blogDate">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="blogTitle">
    <textarea name="blogContent" id="blogBody"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="blogSubmit">    
  </form>​
</code>
```

Call ajax on button click

```
$("#blogSubmit").on('click',function(){      

$.ajax({
type:'POST', 
url:'****.php', 
data:$('#blogForm').serialize(),
success: function(responseSubmit) { blah blah etc...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea name is blogContent but the id is blogBody. The # selector uses the id, not the name.

Comment: The selector uses the id *of the form*

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to remove your editor - they usually work by using JS to update the hidden textarea after each keystroke, or when the form submits, so that shouldn't make a difference provided the editor is getting that bit right.

I imagine the issue is as Phillip suggested - that your ID and name attributes differ. All the others match up fine. When it serialises it must be using the IDs, and presumably in your script at the other side you're expecting the names to come though (which a normal form submit would do).

Since you're sending via $POST, just do a var_dump($_POST); in your script and then log that to the console or alert it out in your JavaScript - see what exactly is getting sent via AJAX to your script.

If the textarea isn't there under any name, then you know the issue is definitely the editor, and if it is, try manually calling the methodsfor nicEditor which will update the hidden textarea.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajaxSubmit then POST data from textarea of any text editor won't work.

So you have to get the value & put it into hidden field then you can get the POST value like this:

```
<textarea id="safety" name="safety" style="width:600px;height:70px"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="safety_precautions" id="safety_precautions">
```

before ajaxsubmit

```
$('#safety_precautions').val(tinyMCE.get('safety').getContent());
```