# jQuery wont post textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I have a problem with my code it won't send the textarea in the addnews.php

When I use `<input type="text" name="content">`, then it sends but with `<textarea>` it won't send.

jQuery

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    var form = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    var poster = $.post('addnews.php', $(this).serialize());
    poster.done(function(data) {
        $(".result").html(data);
        setTimeout(function() { $(".result").hide(); }, 2000);
        form.reset();
    });
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['rubric'])) { 
    if (empty($_POST['rubric']) && empty($_POST['content'])) { 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error alert-box">Du måste fylla i alla fält.</div>'; 
    }
    else { 
        $rubric = htmlentities($_POST['rubric']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."news(`date`, `poster`)
        VALUES('".time()."', '".$userID."')"; 
        mysql_query($sql);
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."news_contents(`newsID`,  `headline`, `content`)
        VALUES('".$id."', '".$rubric."', '".$_POST['content']."')";
        mysql_query($sql2);
        echo '<div class="alert alert-box alert-success">Klart, nyheten postad.</div>'; 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
echo '<div class="result"></div>';
echo '<form method="post" id="form" style="padding: 5px;">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="rubric" placeholder="Rubrik..." style="width: 778px;
                border-bottom: none;font-size: 10px;
                font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><br>';
    echo '<textarea name="content" class="myTextEditor" style="width: 800px; 
                height: 500px;"></textarea>'; 
    echo '<br><input type="submit" name="addnews" value="Spara" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right" style="font-weight:bold;">
                <a href="?p=news" class="btn btn-mini addbutton pull-right" 
                style="font-weight:bold;margin-right: 10px;">Tillbaka</a>';
echo '</form>';
```

In the PHP file, I did a `print_r($_POST)` and it sends the content, but it is empty even if I write something.

Comment: If your `<textarea>` is missing attribute `name` then `.serialize()` doesn't work on that field. So it should be `<textarea name="content" ...>`, is that the case here?

Comment: Sounds like thsi may be some help to you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115457/jquery-serialize-error-with-textarea-filed`

Comment: @HieuNguyen My textarea have the name content thats why its so weird

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115457/jquery-serialize-error-with-textarea-filed#answers-header Hope this help.... :-)

Comment: Posting your HTML might help

Comment: Are you sure your textarea has content in the right place? value= works for input, textarea text goes between the <opening> and </closing> tags.

Comment: Side note: You might want to change the `&&` in `if (empty($_POST['rubric']) && empty($_POST['content']))` to `||`, otherwise your error message will only be shown when BOTH fields are empty.

Comment: @biswajitGhosh I only got undefined when i used that

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I posted the html code too.

Comment: @MaximKumpan Yes! i posted the HTML code so you can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect I know what's going on.

Your textarea has the class myTextEditor. Do you happen to have some kind of js rich text editor hanging from that class?

If you do, note that not all text editors modify the morphed textarea directly. Some (like CKEditor) have a special method that updates the textarea with new text. This problem does not show up when you submit the form - only when you try to serialize it or manipulate it via JS.

Check the editor docs (or provide a link to the editor - 'myTextEditor' as a search term is incredibly ambiguous) if this is the case.

**Update:**

Since you are using TinyMCE, the answer to your question lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122085/problem-jquery-and-tinymce-textarea-value-doesnt-submit).

In brief:

> before submit call tinyMCE.triggerSave();

Comment: @Tommy, in that case, here's your answer. :)

Comment: @Tommy, No, right before `var poster = $.post('addnews.php', $(this).serialize());`. You see, `$("#form").submit(function(event)` is a trigger. When you reach triggerSave(), it executes immediately after being read, and anything inside `$("#form").submit` - only after submitting the form.

Comment: Don't mention it, glad to be of help.